# How to change URL Key for different store view - Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have to change my URL Key in store views.

from foo.com/en/**foo**/foo.html to foo.com/it/**bar**/foo.html

I tried to change the URL Key through the admin panel but it dit not work. I'm still waiting :)

[image]

On my database:

```
mysql> select attribute_id from prod_eav_attribute where attribute_code in('url_key','url_path');
+--------------+
| attribute_id |
+--------------+
|           43 |
|           57 |
|           97 |
|           98 |
+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select is_global from prod_catalog_eav_attribute where attribute_id IN (43, 57, 97, 98);
+-----------+
| is_global |
+-----------+
|         0 |
|         0 |
|         0 |
|         0 |
+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the url path should work from the backend. You can use the following queries to debug:

#### get entity type id for categories (result = 3 for me )

```
select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_category'
```

#### get the attribute id (result = 57 for me)

```
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'url_path' and entity_type_id = 3
```

#### get url path values for specific category id 7919

```
select store_id, value from catalog_category_entity_varchar where entity_type_id = 3 and attribute_id = 57 and entity_id = 7919
```

Hope it helps!